# filtering rows with duplicate occurances in one column based on AND logic/condition in other column

Tags: r, filter, duplicates, tidyverse

Working in the Tidyverse, and given the below data set, I want to filter to return the rows with duplicates in column 'a' if the duplicates are one each "L" and "A" from column 'b'. Do keep in mind that column 'a' are factors, and column 'b' are characters.

I have tried to group and filter, but not working, 
OR returns original data frame, AND returns an 
empty dataframe.

```
my_data <- data.frame(a=c("A","B","B","C","D","D","E"),
                      b=c("L","L","A","L","L","A","L"))



new_data <- my_data %>%
                    group_by(a) %>%
                    filter(b == "L" & b == "A")


The results should look like this:
a  b
B  L
B  A
D  L
D  A
```

Comment: `my_data %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(n() > 1, b %in% c('L', 'A'))`?

Comment: @Axeman's solution works for this specific dataset. But it will also return rows where both duplicates of a value from `a` has one of the letters "L" or "A" (e.g. `b = 'L'`).

Slightly changing it will make sure that both 'L' and 'A' are represented for a given duplicate of `a`:
`my_data %>% group_by(a) %>% filter(n() > 1, all(c("L", "A") %in% b))`

Comment: Thanks wibom, and Axeman. wibom's solution worked perfectly!